# Easing the download of a regularly uploaded pdf

Tags: uploads, links

I have a Wordpress page.

The user of it, who is not a computer expert, weekly uploads a one-page pdf onto a page. The menu has a link to the page, and then the visitors can click on the ever fresh link on the page and get the current pdf.

So this is two steps: menu->page->pdf

I would like to have it easier: menu entry -> pdf

The problem is, due to the weekly upload, the underlying URL is changing weekly.

I am not sure if he could edit the link of the menu entry to have the correct URL after upload -- he is not computer savvy. It is important that he could do this so he need not rely on me.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to give the option to add the file to the homepage. Then once a week when he needs to update it he can just go in and replace the existing file by uploading the new one. If the description or anything has to change then you can just add the additional field which he can modify too.

Advanced Custom Fields Plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Example of file output:

```
$pdf_file = get_field('pdf_file_field');
if ($pdf_file) {
    echo '<div class="pdf-link"><a href="' . $pdf_file['url'] . '">Download Now</a></div>';
}
```